# Menu button not opening

Tags: javascript, button, menu

I have a "hamburger" navigation menu button that appears when my WordPress site loads on tablets and smartphones and it is supposed to open when clicked on, but it doesn't.

I get the following error in the Chrome browser console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Here is the JavaScript code I have in my `footer.php` file:

```js
<script src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?

Comment: I forgot to give the url to my website where I am experiencing this problem. It is http://www.mattriale.com

Comment: Anyone? Can someone please help me?